# C: signal function (parameters?)

Tags: c, signals

I have the following c code:

```
void handler(int n) {
    printf("n value: %i\n");
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGTSTP, handler);   // ^Z at keyboard
    for(int n = 0; ; n++) {
    }   
}
```

I am curious what the n parameter is in the handler function.  When you press `^Z` it usually prints either: `8320`, `-1877932264` or `-1073743664`.  What are these numbers?

---

**Edit:**  Ops I wrote my printf wrong.  I corrected it to be:

```
void handler(int n) {
    printf("n value: %i\n",n);
}
```

Now the value of n is always: 18.  What is this 18?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't passed any number to printf(). Should be:

```
void handler(int n) {
    printf("n value: %i \n", n);
}
```

The `n` will be the signum you are catching, in your case 20. See [`man 2 signal`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) for a description. Also note that the manpage recommends using [`sigaction()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) instead of `signal`.

Answer (score 6):

The way you've written it, it prints out random garbage. The reason is, you don't pass `n` to `printf`. It should be

```
void handler(int n) {
    printf("n value: %i \n", n);
}
```

This way, it prints the signal number.

Answer (score 6):

The signal handler parameter is the **signal number**, so you can use one function for many signals. See [`signal(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Signal/).

Answer (score 2):

The single argument for a signal handler function is the signal number (unsurprisingly). From `man signal`:

```
 No    Name         Default Action       Description
 18    SIGTSTP      stop process         stop signal generated from keyboard (CTRL + Z usually)
```

Answer (score 0):

They're stand-ins for the nasal demons.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the signal number. Check this [link](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html#Job-Control-Signals) for more information on job control signals like the one you have used.

```
The SIGTSTP signal is an interactive stop signal. Unlike SIGSTOP, this signal 
can be handled and ignored.
Your program should handle this signal if you have a special need 
to leave files or system tables in a secure state when a process is 
stopped. For example, programs that turn off echoing should handle 
SIGTSTP so they can turn echoing back on before stopping.
```